# JavaScript Chrome extension using variables and functions from different JS files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have 5 `content_script.js` (1-5) and each contains its own function inside each of these content scripts. However, I ran into an issue where I need to use a variable or function from another content script, it throws me an error saying variable/function undefined. So I have to redeclare the variable again in the same script to be able to use it.

Is there a way to pass variables and functions from one content script to another? In this case I want to use the `setSelectedValue()` function and `objSelect` variable.

**content_script:**

```
function clickUpdate() {
    var updateArray = document.getElementsByClassName("updateButton");
    var saveArray = document.getElementsByClassName("saveButton");
    var updateArraySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".updateButton");

[].slice.call(updateArray).forEach(function(item) {

    if (saveArray.length == 0)

        setSelectedValue(objSelect, "P"); //it doesnt recognize this function from my other content_script
        console.log("object select is: " + objSelect); //it also doesnt recongize this variable

    });

console.log("this is the update array legnth: " + updateArray.length);
console.log("this is the save array legnth: " + saveArray.length);
console.log("this is the update array selector: " + updateArraySelector); 
}
clickUpdate();
```

**content_script1:**

```
var objSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.engpf')
//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, "P");

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {

    for (var i=0; i<selectObj.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<selectObj[i].options.length; j++){

        if (selectObj[i].options[j].value == valueToSet) {
            selectObj[i].options[j].selected = true;                
        }
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: I think you can use messages to do that, but I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: Depends on how you've declared them in manifest.json. Add it to the question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].